# Am I safe from SQL-injections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I'm using a simple cms as backend to my website where I'm able to update news and such. I want to be safe from SQL-injections, so I'm wondering if this code is considered to be safe or if there's something I can do to make it safer:

```
if($_POST) {
    if(isset($_POST['title']) and (isset($_POST['content']) and     ($_POST['added']))) {
        $title = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."'";
        $content = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content'])."'";
        $added = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['added'])."'";

        if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!=''){
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET title = ".$title.",     added =".$added.", content = ".$content."  WHERE id = ".$_POST['id']);
            $msg = "News Updated Successfully";
        }else{
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, content, added) values($title, $content, $added)") or die("err0r");
            $msg = "News Added Successfully";
        }
    }
```

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: `Am I safe from SQL injections?' -- Without looking at the question: no (since you need to ask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not sanitizing  `$_POST['id']`.

Do an `intval()` on it, or (better) refuse processing altogether if the ID is not an integer (assuming ID is an `int` field).

```
if (!is_numeric($_POST['id'])
 die ("Invalid ID");
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!=''){ into if (!is_int($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!=''){. Does this make it safe?

Comment: Post values are strings, so is_int($_POST['id']) will be false even if $_POST['id] contains a valid numeric value.

Comment: @Arjan arrgh, you're right. Fixed, thanks. @Jaoza see update (but keep the `isset()` checks in place)

Comment: Won't `is_int((int)$_POST['id'])` always be true?

Comment: @Denis you're right  too, don't know where my head is today! :) Fixed - a pure `is_numeric()` will do to protect against SQL injection (even though it'll match some non-integer values as well.)

Answer (score 3):

One thing you should do is making shure the ID is integer (which is probably needs to be):

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this after I've tried the first answer I got. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

> if there's something I can do to make it safer

Yes, you can use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) interface with prepared statements, so that the query is built separately from the data (which is bound later) and no kind of injection is ever possible.